# Mongoose query returns no values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently creating a MEAN application to allow a user to create a football team from a list of ownedPlayers.  Currently however when I attempt to make a http.get call to the ownedPlayers collection in MongoDB it always returns an empty array.

My mongoose model for OwnedPlayers is as follows.

```
var OwnedPlayers = mongoose.model('OwnedPlayers', {
    userid: String,
    playerid: String,
    position: String
});
```

The endpoint and query is as follows.

```
app.get('/api/ownedPlayers', function (req, res) {
    console.log('userid used in request', req.query.userid)
    console.log('position used in request', req.query.position)

    OwnedPlayers.find({
        userid: req.query.userid, position: req.query.position
    }, function (err, owned)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            res.send(err);
        }
        console.log('owned',owned);
        res.json(owned);
    });
});
```

I can confirm that the values in req.query.userid and req.query.position do match a single record in my ownedPlayers collection.  This can be seen by my nodejs output below.

```
App listening on port 8080
GET /api/teams/57f50267418cb72fd020196a 304 31.936 ms - -
userid used in request 57f50267418cb72fd020196a
position used in request goal
owned []
GET /api/ownedPlayers?userid=57f50267418cb72fd020196a&position=goal 304 32.903 ms - -
```

I can also confirm that the key names are correct as userid and position.

The document I would expect to be returned when userid = 57f50267418cb72fd020196a and position = position= goal is as follows.

```
_id:57f7717ab1f0f22f3c3950b9
userid:57f50267418cb72fd020196a
playerid:57f7797e00ea2a0dc8609701
position:goal
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm very new to mongodb and mean applications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you create instance of `OwnedPlayers`?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean?  I included the section where I outline the data model to be used for OwnedPlayers, isn't this the same thing?  Apologies if this is a silly question, still wearing my noob stripes.  I make actual http request from an angular 2 provider.  I'll include the code for it. and where I make the call in a view typescript file in my initial question.

Comment: Remove angular code, show the server code of creating `OwnedPlayers`

Comment: Try changing .find to .findOne

Comment: I don't have any code for creating OwnedPlayers,  I currently add them manually to the collection from mongocompass.  I intend to add this once I have the get request working, if this is incorrect I'll add the post endpoint. Do I need to have an app.post endpoint to be able to retrieve the information?

Comment: @Tom I tried this and it didn't help although I'm unsure how it would do as I want all the records associated with a userid and a position, not just a single one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that since I was using an collection with documents which weren't created via mongoose it wasn't finding the collection correctly.

By passing in the collection name as a third parameter when creating my models this explicitly sets the collection name and points mongoose in the right direction.